# Cannot make editable column in jqGrid editable

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have searched all available resources but to no avail. I was trying to make one column editable (see column 7 below), but so far nothing works. I have already set the editable property to true. My guess is that it has something to do with the grid attributes set, but I just cant figure out which attribute I need to edit so my editable column can work.

```
$('#pGrdList0').jqGrid({
    "url" : "clientArray",
    "editurl" : "server.php",
    "datatype" : "local",
    "width" : "900",
    "height" : "338",
    "rowNum" : "1000",
    "colNames" : 
        [ "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10" ],
    "colModel" :
        [ {"name" : "g1", "index" : "g1", "width" : "115", "align" : "left", "edittype" : null, "formatter" : null, "formatoptions" : null, "editoptions" : null, "editable" : false},
          {"name" : "g2", "index" : "g2", "width" : "15", "align" : "right", "edittype" : null, "formatter" : null, "formatoptions" : null, "editoptions" : null, "editable" : false},
          {"name" : "g3", "index" : "g3", "width" : "68", "align" : "right", "edittype" : null, "formatter" : null, "formatoptions" : null, "editoptions" : null, "editable" : false},
          {"name" : "g4", "index" : "g4", "width" : "68", "align" : "right", "edittype" : null, "formatter" : null, "formatoptions" : null, "editoptions" : null, "editable" : false},
          {"name" : "g5", "index" : "g5", "width" : "68", "align" : "right", "edittype" : null, "formatter" : null, "formatoptions" : null, "editoptions" : null, "editable" : false},
          {"name" : "g6", "index" : "g6", "width" : "68", "align" : "right", "edittype" : null, "formatter" : null, "formatoptions" : null, "editoptions" : null, "editable" : false},
          {"name" : "g7", "index" : "g7", "width" : "68", "align" : "right", "formatter" : numberFormatter, "formatoptions" : {thousandsSeparator:',',decimalPlaces:0,defaultValue:''}, "editoptions" : "{maxlength: 9, dataInit:setImeDisabled}", "editable" : true},
          {"name" : "g8", "index" : "g8", "width" : "68", "align" : "right", "edittype" : null, "formatter" : null, "formatoptions" : null, "editoptions" : null, "editable" : false},
          {"name" : "g9", "index" : "g9", "width" : "80", "align" : "right", "edittype" : null, "formatter" : null, "formatoptions" : null, "editoptions" : null, "editable" : false},
          {"name" : "g10", "index" : "g10", "width" : "215", "align" : "left", "edittype" : "text", "formatter" : null, "formatoptions" : null, "editoptions" : {maxLength:30, dataInit:setImeEnabled}, "editable" : true} ],
    "pager" : "#pGrdList0nav",
    "viewrecords" : false,
    "cellEdit" : true,
    "cellsubmit" : "clientArray",
    "multiselect" : false,
    "forceFit" : false,
    "shrinkToFit" : false,
    "pgbuttons" : false,
    "pginput" : false,
    "pgtext" : false,
    "onCellSelect": function(rowid, iCol, cellcontent, e) {
        var grid = $('#pGrdShinkoujoukenichiran0');
        grid.setSelection(rowid, true);
    }
});
```

Comment: please, let me knwo if it wokrd out for you or not?

Comment: I have the same problem ... if you could fixed please share

Answer (score 3):

well i find nothing wrong with your code, i didnt test it but i think you should write it like this

editable:true....without double quotes

Answer (score 0):

I had something similar happen to me... Remember that jqgrid is modular, so you have to request the editing options to be included in your copy.

So when you download jqgrid, be sure that all of the editing options checked.